# How to open mysql workbench in browser like phpmyadmin?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, server, mysql-workbench

I'm developling web application using Node.js and mysql data base (workbench).
and using azure server(ubuntu virtual machine). I have install mysql-workbench in ubuntu server.and working on command line.I just uploaded my code through ftp server.
Now I want to open mysql-workbench to import data base and work with.
Is there any way to open workbench through browser like phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. phpmyadmin is a php application that designed to run on a webserver with browser, mysql-workbench is a native application.

Comment: Yes, I have got this. I Grant remote access permissions (bind address) and Access database through native mysql-workbench through TCP/IP over ssh.